# Current directory in Apache 2 config file

Tags: configuration, apache2

Is it possible to use a variable for the parent directory of an included Apache 2 configuration file? Something like this maybe?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot ${PARENTDIR}/../docs
</VirtualHost>
```